# How to sum first elements from lists in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Function should works like this:

```
sumFstElems [[1,2],[10,122,1],[12],[0],[1,1000]] = 24
```

I know that this prints first elements from lists:

```
fun xs = fmap head xs
```

This sum elements in list:

```
mysum (x:xs) = x + mysum xs
```

I have a problem with combining these two functions to give the expected result.

Comment: What should `sumFstElems [[]]` return?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would write the function:

```hs
sumFstElems :: [[Int]] -> Int
sumFstElems nss = sum (map head nss)
```

With `fun` and `mysum` it can be written as

```hs
sumFstElems :: [[Int]] -> Int
sumFstElems nss = mysum (fun nss)
```

or

```hs
sumFstElems :: [[Int]] -> Int
sumFstElems = mysum . fun
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider some basics:

```
Prelude> lst = [[1, 2], [6], [8, 9]]
Prelude> map head lst
[1,6,8]
Prelude> sum (map head lst)
15
```

Now, let's make a function:

```
Prelude> sumFstElems lst = sum (map head lst)
Prelude> sumFstElems lst
15
```

But what if we use `.` to compose the functions `sum` and `map head`, and then apply that to the `lst` argument?

```
Prelude> sumFstElems lst = (sum . map head) lst
Prelude> sumFstElems lst
15
```

That works. But then we don't need to explicitly list the argument.

```
Prelude> sumFstElems = sum . map head
Prelude> sumFstElems lst
15
```

Of course, this will fail if any of the lists contained in `lst` are empty. Given that this is possible, maybe we should filter those out.

```
Prelude> sumFstElems = sum . map head . filter (/= [])
Prelude> sumFstElems [[1, 2], [6], [8, 9], [], [4]]
19
```

A list comprehension provides a way of combining the filtering and mapping.

```
Prelude> sumFstElems lst = sum [head x | x <- lst, x /= []]
Prelude> sumFstElems [[1, 2], [6], [8, 9], [], [4]]
19
```

Comment: [`null :: Foldable t => t a -> Bool`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:null) might fit well with your approach.

Comment: Also [`transpose :: [[a]] -> [[a]]`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:transpose).

Comment: If you're going to do a list comprehension, use `[x | x:_ <- lst]`. This doesn't incur an `Eq` constraint (and is more concise to boot). I would suggest a similar technique to avoid `(/=)` in the filter version. The standard total alternative to `head` is `take 1`. So, `sum . concatMap (take 1)`.